# Disable "Recently used" in GTK file/directory selector

Tags: xfce, gtk, file-management

Can I completely disable "Recently Used" feature in GTK's file / directory selector?

[image: Recently Used]

Sometimes programs default to this but since it's not useful in my work-flow and with the way I organize my files, it only adds confusion:

- I usually just expect to start from my `$HOME`, so I get surprised
  by the list of folders
- Also in case of file saving, I'm annoyed by the fact that you can't just
  type in the name and hit Enter--you have to type a path or select one

I'm using Xfce 4.8 on Debian Wheezy and this feature was not available in older Xfce (in Squeeze).  I found [a post on Xfce-users' mailing list](http://xfce.10915.n7.nabble.com/OT-Disabling-quot-Recently-Used-quot-in-file-chooser-td2536.html#none) regarding this feature, but without any useful output.

Is it possible to simply turn this off and default to `$HOME`?

Comment: Sadly it seems you're right.  Although this is really a nasty thing to hard-code since it obviously breaks workflows like "Hit Ctrl+S, type filename, hit Enter".
Hopefully one day it will change and we'll have answer...

Comment: I wouldn't hold my breath... GTK/Gnome devs are known to be really stubborn (a classic example being the `CTRL+DEL` stupidity implemented in Nautilus). FWIW, wrt file chooser, I usually hit `Ctrl+S`, type filename then `Ctrl+Tab` then arrows (as many times as needed) then `Enter`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@MartinVegter

There is a file `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`. It should look like Stefano wrote:

```
[Filechooser settings]
LocationMode=path-bar
ShowHidden=false
ShowSizeColumn=true
GeometryX=377
GeometryY=132
GeometryWidth=612
GeometryHeight=528
SortColumn=name
SortOrder=ascending
StartupMode=recent
```

There was no `DefaultFolder` variable in this file, but I found the `StartupMode=recent` var which I changed to `StartupMode=cwd`. This only works on GTK 2 applications like `mousepad`.

I don't know there is settings file for GTK 3 apps like `gedit`, but it seems that GTK 3 filechooser already sets the location to the current folder by default.

Answer (score 17):

Note: This answer is for GTK3; all other answers only work for GTK2.

To disable the recent files list, add the following to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (create it and its directory if needed):

```
[Settings]
gtk-recent-files-enabled=0
```

To pre-select the current working directory, run

```
dconf write /org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/startup-mode \"cwd\"
```

or use a GUI program like `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Well indeed it does disable the Recent item (upvoting...) but no item is pre-selected, which still feels a bit strange and is cumbersome to use with keyboard only.  Maybe there's similar item as `StartupMode=recent` in GTK2...?

Comment: I've managed to figure that out as well; I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sounded promising, but unfortunately, doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: I believe it depends on how the application codes the call to the file dialog. If the application does not specify a default path then the `dconf` setting mentioned above should work. If the application does specify a default directory then I'm not sure if it's possible to override it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can disable it: open or create `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` and add these lines to it:

```
[Filechooser Settings]
DefaultFolder=cwd
```

Replace `cwd` with `last` if you prefer to start with last selected folder instead.

I think this hidden option should also work for gtk3, but I did not test it.

Comment: Sorry, but did not work for me--still Recently Used is offered and pre-selected.  I tried even logging in/out and using mousepad, which depends on libgtk2.0-0.

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to change the variable `StartupMode` from `recent` to `cwd` in the same file.

Comment: @jeremija - could you please post the config that works? What exactly do I have to add?

Comment: @MartinVegter see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 0):

StartupMode from recent to cwd
Just changing that variable works very well for me, using opensuse xfce.
Now the recent list is available but not persistent
eg if i open an '*.tap' file F.U.S.E emulator opens in the work directory were the actual file is so NOW the next save or load is in THAT directory.
If i combine my ASM pages then i easily can find the different directories with the recentlist. thats flexible