# Show file system instead of "places" in gtk file chooser

Tags: desktop-environment, desktop, gtk, gtk3

In almost any program, when I click on `open`, a file chooser dialog opens as shown below. This dialog shows `Recent`, `Home`, `Desktop` and so on.

[image]

This is extremely annoying. I am not using `Desktop` to store data, and I don't care about `Recent`. I would like to get consistently same view each time the open dialog appears, regardless of what I happen to have opened recently.

Also, it can be seen on my screenshot, how idiotic this dialog window is. I have `tmpfs` mounted on `/tmp`, and another `tmpfs` mounted in `/home/<user>/tmp`.

Yet, in the `Locations` list, these two mountpoints are only referred to as `tmp` and are indistinguishable.

Ideally on the left, I would like to see my home directory in the upper part, and plain good old filesystem tree starting with `/` in the lower part.

Or maybe even better, only show filesystem tree on the left, but with current location `/home/<user>/` alredy "pre-selected" automatically, and contents of my `home` displayed on the right.

I can remove `Recent` by adding the following to `.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
gtk-recent-files-enabled=false
```

But still, Desktop is there in the upper part, and the absolute chaos of randomly assembled shares is there in the lower part.

**In GTK2/GTK3 how can I bring back some order and logic to the file chooser, as described above ?**

**Update June, 2020: I am using Openbox on Debian 10, with GTK3 library without any desktop environment. Also I have updated the screenshot.**

Comment: I've been researching this in vain and do not believe it to be possible.

Comment: Wouldn' t it be worth asking a new question targeted at gtk3, so the old question, its answers, etc., are easier to read and follow?
Some may still be interested in such a track, and it would get somewhat confusing.

Comment: An edited question should ideally not invalidate any existing answers.

Comment: @JeffSchaller & Martin Vegter I have updated the question to avoid invalidating the old one while keeping the focus on the updated version, roll back the last edit if it is not suitable to your question. In any case there was no answer neither for GTK2 nor for GTK3 as a correct solution require writing a patch.

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox you can configure not to use the "system" file chooser but its own by setting `ui.allow_platform_file_picker` to `false` in the `about:config` window.  I know this is only one program but better than nothing?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Often times it is hard to satisfy the two following requirements (which I deem reasonable) at the same time: 1) not write a whole new question/answer, 2) keep it readable for either of the two versions (GTK2/GTK3, in this case).
If I were to sacrifice one of the two (to meet your "ideal case", which is the same as mine), that would be the first... then my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is around for quite some time, but a simple solution to omit the growing list of mostly useless mount point items in the sidebar still appears not to exist yet.

As a quick fix, the following patch disables all places besides the home directory, the user bookmarks and the "Recent" item (if configured so).

Perhaps this is helpful.

```
--- gtk+3.0-3.24.24.orig/gtk/gtkplacessidebar.c
+++ gtk+3.0-3.24.24/gtk/gtkplacessidebar.c
@@ -106,6 +106,16 @@
  * - .has-open-popup when a popup is open for a row
  */
 
+/* Workaround switch for a concise places sidebar.
+ *
+ *   2023-01-05 Gundolf Kiefer <gundolf.kiefer@web.de>
+ *
+ * The following switch disables all automatically generated places from the
+ * sidebar except the home directory and the user-defined bookmarks.
+ */
+#define SHORT_SIDEBAR 1
+
+
 /* These are used when a destination-side DND operation is taking place.
  * Normally, when a common drag action is taking place, the state will be
  * DROP_STATE_NEW_BOOKMARK_ARMED, however, if the client of GtkPlacesSidebar
@@ -1097,6 +1107,8 @@ update_places (GtkPlacesSidebar *sidebar
   g_object_unref (start_icon);
   g_free (home_uri);
 
+#if SHORT_SIDEBAR == 0
+
   /* desktop */
   if (sidebar->show_desktop)
     {
@@ -1416,6 +1428,8 @@ update_places (GtkPlacesSidebar *sidebar
     }
   g_list_free (mounts);
 
+#endif    // SHORT_SIDEBAR == 0
+
   /* add bookmarks */
   bookmarks = _gtk_bookmarks_manager_list_bookmarks     (sidebar->bookmarks_manager);
```

Comment: thank you! that works beautifully

Comment: I have another annoyance in gtkfilechooser: when I accidentally click on the "name" column header, it changes the sort order between ascending/descending. This usually happens when I want to click on the first file, biut accidentally click on the header. I only ever want ascending, I don't want this to be toggle-ble. Can this be "locked" ? I can create a new question for that

Answer (score 4):

## GTK File Chooser?

A perfect solution would be an upstream commit/patch to at least [gtkfilechooserdialog.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.c) and [gtkfilechooserwidget.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/master/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c) to implement additional features answering this question needs and making it available to all users through updates. The documentation for the current implementation is available for [GTK2](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFileChooser.html) and [GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html).

---

## Patching it locally?

A patch for such features is not a quick task and other than the upstream solution, applying such patch locally would require using a custom patched version of the GTK library that may lead to system updates complication.

The other way to apply such patch is by using [LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) environment variable along with a newly developed patching library
to replace the current GTK code with the patched one. this can be applied separately to each application or system wide. Such solution would be considered as a workaround/hack as it's far from being clean but still this can be efficient. (as an additional dev. note, the newly `ld_preload` library may contain code implementing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625609/customizing-gtkfilechooser)).

---

## Any workaround?

For users that have multiple desktop installed (for instance Gnome and KDE) can force some application to use the KDE dialog which is more customizable. As example with `chromium` this can be done with the following

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE chromium
```

There are also other workaround to [replace GTK dialogs](https://superuser.com/questions/944119/replace-gtk-file-dialog-with-alternative) such as [KGtk](https://www.linux-apps.com/content/show.php?content=36077) or [xdg-desktop-portal-kde](https://superuser.com/a/1373504/446140).

Answer (score 2):

## Available customization?

The setting `gtk-recent-files-enabled=false` can be added to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` that would disable the recent entry. Also not directly related but `gtk-recent-files-limit=0` and `gtk-recent-files-max-age=0` can be used as well to disable recent files. For Gtk2 [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134047/120919) solution is used to disable recent files.

Other settings suck as show hidden files or startup mode can be set with

```
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden true
gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser startup-mode cwd
```

Screenshot of `dconf-editor` with other available settings

[image: FileChooser Settings]

[image: FileChooser Startup Mode]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have gtk2 installed to verify this, but you can try this:

Add `StartupMode=cwd` to `$HOME/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`.

I got this from this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2160654.html

Comment: It's not a GTK2 desktop that controls this, the applications that are GTK2 vs. GTK3 will decide on picking up this option or not. That being said all GTK2 apps will then present the file chooser dialog using the current working dir. with `cwd` set as above.

Comment: @arnefm - the file `$HOME/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini` did not exist. When I create it and add `StartupMode=cwd` and restart, I see no effect.

Comment: @slm: the ini file is automatically picked up by GTK+, this is the [relevant code](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechoosersettings.c?id=2.24.24#n72).

Comment: @Martin Vegter: `gtkfilechooser.ini` must be already present there (it is [saved](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechoosersettings.c?id=2.24.24#n388) every time you exit the filechooser dialog). If not you probably have a non standard `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, wrong privileges or some sort of other file system problems.

Comment: OP wants the file chooser to default to `/` (not `cwd`) which is not possible. As per the official gtk2 [docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFileChooser.html): _The StartupMode key controls whether the file chooser starts up showing the list of recently-used files, or the contents of the current working directory. Respectively, the values can be_ `recent` _or_ `cwd`.  The same applies to gtk3, you can only choose between `recent` or `cwd` (those values are hard-coded).

Answer (score 1):

As people already said here, you can set `StartupMode=cwd` in `~/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini`. This file exists already, if it is GTK+2, but I am not sure if your screenshot shows GTK+3.

In this case insert this line into your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`:

```
gtk-recent-files-enabled=false
```

If you want "/" to appear as first view, you need to `chdir /` before starting the application.

Comment: neither has any effect. It still looks exactly same as on the screenshot.

Comment: I checked on Firefox, Thunderbird and Gimp. It seems to work for me. What application is this? Maybe it's programmed that way that it ignores the system's default behavior.

Comment: all applications (gpicview, leafpad, .Now I tried Firefox, and that's same as well.

Comment: in GTK3 you have org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser last-folder-uri '/this/is/shown/at/start' you can edit this in, for example, debconf

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: There is no *Configurable* way of achieving this. Available options are not simple.**

As stated here and elsewhere (e.g., a related post that you already saw [Disable "Recently used" in GTK file/directory selector](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74031/disable-recently-used-in-gtk-file-directory-selector)), options are `recent` or `cwd`.

Now, to remove `Desktop` from the dialog, and to get it reorganized as intend to do, it seems not available as a configuration.
That would require changing code in GTK3.
I guess the options are doing it yourself, or file a *feature request* and wait.

I am giving here a few pointers about where is the related code residing, in case you want to commit an update for this.
This is clearly not a finalized solution to your intended changes (that would be a lot of work, good for closing the as-of-yet-not-existing *feature request*).

The struct [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html)
is created with [`gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html#gtk-file-chooser-dialog-new).

It calls `gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new_valist` in turn ([gtkfilechooserdialog.c:769](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.c), as of this writing).

The dialog is finally created with ([gtkfilechooserdialog.c:727](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.c))

```
g_object_new (GTK_TYPE_FILE_CHOOSER_DIALOG,
                     "title", title,
                     "action", action,
                     NULL);
```

so you would have likely to find where to add calls to one of the methods for adding entries to the [GtkFileChooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html):
[`gtk_file_chooser_add_choice`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-add-choice),
[`gtk_file_chooser_add_filter`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-add-filter),
[`gtk_file_chooser_add_shortcut_folder`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-add-shortcut-folder) (probably the most useful), and
[`gtk_file_chooser_add_shortcut_folder_uri`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooser.html#gtk-file-chooser-add-shortcut-folder-uri),
with the locations of your liking to change this.